# How to store user input from a button and then compare to an array

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am trying to re-create the mastermind game using C# and .net Maui in Visual studio 2022. I am currently having trouble in a few different areas. The main issue I am having is I don't know how to store the user input from a button.
What I would like to achieve is: the user selects a colour, this would adjust the colour of the button and I would store the colour into an array. Later on, I would then compare this array to my answer list array to see if the user is correct.

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BoxView b = (BoxView)sender;
    currentGuessPeg.BackgroundColor = b.Color;
    currentGuessPeg.BorderColor = Colors.Transparent;
    GridColourPicker.IsVisible = false;
}
```

Currently I am able to switch between colours as shown below but I don't know how to store these answers. Still very new to c# and very confused on storing data from a button.

[image: Colour change]

[image: Colour change 2]

Any help is much apricated.

Comment: It’s hard to give specific advice when you haven’t posted any code.  Generally speaking you would create a variable to store the value of the user selection

Comment: i believe this is the code where i can change the color of each button 
         BoxView b = (BoxView)sender;
        currentGuessPeg.BackgroundColor = b.Color;
        currentGuessPeg.BorderColor = Colors.Transparent;
        GridColourPicker.IsVisible = false;                                                                 I just dont know how to store the data.

Comment: What data do you want to store?  Create a variable of type Color and set it to the selected Color if that’s what you need

Comment: Update ([edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74997301/edit)) your question with the relevant code...it's almost closed.

Comment: i have an array created with the colours that is randomly giving to the buttons on the top row. on the Second row i need to try and guess the colours on the top row but when i select a colour i need to store an array of the colours i guessed

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code instead of trying to describe it.  This has been suggested several times

Comment: @TimmyForde this is some school project for bulls and cows game. Few seconds in google will give you 100 working C# solutions that you can use.

Comment: Why not just compare the `BackgroundColor` of the corresponding controls themselves?...don't they all have names that you can reference via code? Technically, you could create a list/array of the random controls, and a list/array of the user guess controls, then iterate over them and compare the `BackgroundColor`s to see if they all match.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `List` to store the user selections

```
List<Color> selections = new List<Color>();
```

Then every time the user makes a selection, add it to the list

```
selections.Add(b.Color);
```